# My navbar list elements are moving to next line, How can I position them to fit in single line?

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors

I added li items but the last item is leaving the navbar and getting below it [newline],
I want them to style in such a manner that they all will appear in single Line inside navbar
I am a noob, a little explanation would be appreciated...
Thank you Here is my code
HTML CODE:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #e4f5ff;
    padding: 0;
}

nav {
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #022534;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 20px;

}

nav li {
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    display: inline-flex;
    padding: 10px 5%;
    background-color: none;
    font-size: 35px;
    margin: auto;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #e4f5ff;
}

#Logo {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="" id="Logo">Myweb</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Categories</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Latest</a></li>
                <li><a href="">More</a></li>
                <li><a href="">About-Us</a></li>
                <li id="login"><a href="">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: You could reduce the padding: 10px 5%; given to nav li to make the list items fit in a single line ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The font-size of 35 and padding of 5% is quite large. If the elements don't fit in a line, it will have to overflow. What you can do is lower the font size and left/right padding of the li elements so they fit better in a line. However, keep in mind you will have to style for responsiveness when the screen gets smaller, such as turning the navbar into a hamburger menu.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #e4f5ff;
    padding: 0;
}

nav {
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #022534;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: auto;

}

nav li {
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    display: inline-flex;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    background-color: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: auto;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #e4f5ff;
}

#Logo {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="" id="Logo">Myweb</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Categories</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Latest</a></li>
                <li><a href="">More</a></li>
                <li><a href="">About-Us</a></li>
                <li id="login"><a href="">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply, do `li{width:16.66%}` so that they will have enough width just to fit within each other in the ul or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get more in-depth possibilities to shape your layout, try Bootstrap. It's a really straightforward tool to help you deal with issues like the one you have (or had). Among other things it lets you dynamically adjust the width of your listed links depending on the size of the media window. Check out the docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/overview/

Answer (score 1):

Just add/change the following in your css

```
nav ul { display: flex; }
nav li { padding: 10px; }
```